# How can I make a pictureBox that, when clicked, will display some text to a label?

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I'm using Visual Studio, so I already have drag-and-dropped some pictureBoxes in there, and they have names and pictures.  I just want to be able to click them and have a label say the name of the person in the picture that was clicked.

This is what I currently have (for the pictureBox only)

```
private void captainFalcon_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{  
    Label.Show("Captain Falcon");  

}
```

FINAL EDIT: Everything is working now, I just followed everyone's suggestions!

Comment: What is the name of your label? You need to be setting the Text Property.

Comment: yeah, I changed my code here to what you suggested, but I'm getting 2 errors, semicolon expected, and "Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement"

Comment: You need to select the checkmark to the left of the answer that helped you. That way you will get some rep and they will to.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you need?

```
private void captainFalcon_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label.Text = "Captain Falcon";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
private void captainFalcon_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    xxxxxx.Text ="Captain Falcon";
}
```

and instead of xxxxx use your label name.
Select your label on designer, look at its properties, and use its "(Name)" property.

For example if your label name is characterName, then your code will be

```
characterName.Text ="Captain Falcon";
```

Comment: So I changed it to that, but the "label1.Text ="Captain Falcon"; says that there is a "; expected" and another error that says "Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement"

Answer (score 1):

Something like below will work.

```
private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = "Captain Falcon";
}
```

Obviously change the control names (pictureBox1 and label1) to match yours.